# How to write a N1QL query for the below requirement

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the below project records.

```
"projectkey1" : { 
 "name" : "project name",
"productDetails" :{
"productKey1":"requested",
"productkey2":"requested"
} 
"type" : "project"
}

Now each product is stored as below are
 "productKey1"(key) : {"description" : "product1" , "type" : "product"}
```

We have multiple project records but what products are associated with the project is shown in the above key as key value pairs with the actual product key as a key in the project record. Also there is no limit on how many product keys a project can have. Given these requirements how can i write a N1ql that will give the projectname and the product description in the same json

Some thing like

```
 [{ 
    "name" : "project name",
    "product list" : ["product description1", "product description2"]
    },
    { 
    "name" : "project name2",
    "product list" : ["product description3", "product description4"]
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(name ) WHERE type = "project";

SELECT p.name,
       (SELECT RAW pd.description
        FROM default AS pd USE KEYS OBJECT_NAMES(p.productDetails)
        WHERE pd.type = "product"
       ) AS productList
FROM default AS p
WHERE p.type = "project"
      AND p.name IS NOT NULL;
```